# memcpy - cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I am trying to use memcpy but it gives me a

runtime error : Segmentation fault (Core dumped)

and a compiler warning:  warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]

this is the code

```
unsigned char JMP[6] = {0xE9, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xC3};
unsigned long JMPSize = ...;

//copy jump size to jump instruction at second byte (this is where i get the error)
memcpy((uint8_t*)JMP[1],(void*)JMPSize, 4);
```

Comment: Possibly you want &JMP[1]

Comment: (uint8_t*)&JMP[1] looks like what you trying to do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither `JMP[1]` nor `JMPSize` are pointers. This means that `memcpy` will interpret the actual values of the variables as pointers, which will then point to somewhere way off and lead to undefined behavior.

You need to use the address-of operator `&` to make them pointers:

```
memcpy(&JMP[1], &JMPSize, 4);
```

Generally, if a functions takes a `void *` argument, or returns `void *`, then *don't* cast the types. Not casting the types will give you warnings, and warnings are in many cases indicators of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jona It only fools the compiler to tread the value of what you're casting as a pointer. In the case of `(uint8_t*)JMP[1]`, it will pass the value `0x90` to `memcpy` as a pointer. I doubt the value `0x90` is pointing to a valid writable area.

Comment: @Jona: A cast only converts the value you give it. It does not take the address of the object you give it. So `(void *) JMPSize` takes the value of `JMPSIZE` and changes its type to a pointer. That gives you a pointer whose value is nonsense, not a proper address. To get the address of an object, you use the `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `JMP` or `JMPSize` pointers but values. So when you cast the variables to pointers, then memcpy will try to copy from the address number stored in`JMP[0]`, to the address number stored in `JMPSize`. Theses memory locations are probably not valid, which makes your program segfault.

Instead you should reference your variables, that is what the `&` operator in C is for:

```
memcpy(&JMP[1], &JMPSize, 4);
```